# Background chromed image

Tags: css

We like to get a background on our responsive site that gives the shiny effect of chromed plating.

The real chrome effect is not possible with css. I think I need a picture instead of only css code. But how can I get the right height + width on pc screen + mobile (responsive). And what will me the size (WxH) to include in the css?

How do we do this in css without downgrading the site speed.
We only found images that do not fit our needs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code which you tried? It's is expected that you first try and then request help with issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use gradient property of CSS3 to make a chromed color effect using white, gray and black shades.

```
.yourclass{ 
    background: linear-gradient(angle, color1, color2);
}
```

Here's the link below to know more about this property.

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can see next examples:
[Example 1](http://jsfiddle.net/antontrollback/nqqc7/)
[Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/3qWYL/3/)

In booth variants you need to use [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) property.

Comment: The examples are not what I like no chrome effect in there.